# What does "We were unable to check for API ACL" in the Magento security check report mean?

Tags: security-scan-tool

We did the Magento security scan.

And got

unknown | Patch API ACL | We were unable to check for API ACL Please check out our Security Best Practices

What is that supposed to mean? Which security best practices?

*EDIT*

Is this about https://magento.com/security/best-practices/restricting-access-anonymous-web-apis -- but doesn't unkown mean, it could not be checked for some reason, not, that is open?